# vercel mern project deployment changes reflecting on deplyment domain but not on static domain

Tags: reactjs, node.js, deployment, build, vercel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHfeL.png)
Here ignore the deployed folder.

build -> frontend (react)
rest of files/folders -> backend

And now whenever I pushes changes on github. Vercel deplyment process occurs and all the changes reflecting on the deployment automatic domain But not on the static domain. I tried Redeploy with not using existing build cache. But it also didn't work. I tried Promote to production but it also not working.

I tried Redeploy with not using existing build cache. But it also didn't work. I tried Promote to production but it also not working. All things works on deployment automatic domain but not on static domain.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.